# Find the index of the column in data frame that contains the string as value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame like this :

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(letters[1:4],"a"),col2 = 1:5,col3 = letters[10:14])
 df
  col1 col2 col3
1    a    1    j
2    b    2    k
3    c    3    l
4    d    4    m
5    a    5    n
```

I want to find the index of the column of `df` that has values matching to string "a".
i.e. it should give me `1` as result.
I tried using which in sapply but its not working.
Anybody knows how to do it without a loop ??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 which(apply(df, 2, function(x) any(grepl("a", x))))
```

The steps are:

1. With `apply` go over each column
2. Search if `a` is in this column with `grepl`
3. Since we get a vector back, use `any` to get `TRUE` if any element has been matched to `a`
4. Finally check `which` elements (columns) are `TRUE` (i.e. contain the searched letter `a`).

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention you were trying to use `sapply()` but were unsuccessful, here's how you can do it:

```
> sapply(df, function(x) any(x == "a"))
 col1  col2  col3 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE 
> which(sapply(df, function(x) any(x == "a")))
 col1 
    1
```

Of course, you can also use the `grep()`/`grepl()` approach if you prefer string matching. You can also wrap your `which()` function with `unname()` if you want just the column number.