# dplyr mutate_: dynamically create name of columns names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm struggeling to achieve the following  (although I already read [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)):

```
require(dplyr)
require(lazyeval)

# data looks like
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("entry1", "entry2"), col2 = c("0x12", "0xA1"))
#     col1 col2
# 1 entry1 0x12
# 2 entry2 0xA1

# must be something like this:
dots <- list(df %>%
  select(col2) %>%
  distinct(col2))

df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate_(.dots = dots)
# target output
#     col1 col2 0x12 0xA1
# 1 entry1 0x12    1  N/A
# 2 entry2 0xA1  N/A    1
```

So I want to generate a **new column which is named after the cell entry** and **set this to one**. This is unlike all other examples I've found so far, where the input columns are dynamically selected (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678435/dynamic-column-names-in-dplyr)) or they're not doing it with dataframe ([but a `data.table`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239778/pass-variable-as-column-name-to-dplyr)). If the N/As are a `0` it won't do any harm and save me a postprocessing step.

Comment: I guess this can be done using `spread` i.e. `library(tidyr);df%>% mutate(ind=1, col3=col2) %>% spread(col3, ind)`

Comment: Your guess was right - thanks so much ! Do you want to post that as answer so you get some points for your efforts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be easily solved by reshaping into wide format with `spread` from `library(tidyr)`.  We create a column of 1 ('ind') and a duplicate of 'col2' ('col3') and then use `spread` to get the expected output.

```
library(tidyr)
df%>% 
  mutate(ind=1, col3=col2) %>% 
  spread(col3, ind)
#     col1 col2 0x12 0xA1
#1 entry1 0x12    1   NA
#2 entry2 0xA1   NA    1
```

Comment: just in case somebody wonders how to reverse that: use `gather(data, key, value, ..., na.rm = FALSE, convert = FALSE)`