# Find the column in data frame with value

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to expand on question: [Find the index of the column in data frame that contains the string as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062402/find-the-index-of-the-column-in-data-frame-that-contains-the-string-as-value)

I have data

```
data<-data.frame(expert=c("class.1","class.4","class.2"),
  choice1=c("class.3","class.8","class.10"),
  score1=c(0.92,0.91,0.30),
  choice2=c("class.1","class.7","class.9"),
  score2=c(0.70,0.78,0.30),
  choice3=c("class.6","class.1","class.2"),
  score3=c(0.01,0.58,0.30),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

I would like to get the score associated with the expert choice.  The goal is to find out if the 1.) choice one is correct, but I need to check if there are scores that the code chosen by the expert is tied.

So in the example data, using dplyr:

```
data %>% mutate(Right=expert==choice1)
```

get part of the answer, but doesn't handle ties.  The answer in [Find the index of the column in data frame that contains the string as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062402/find-the-index-of-the-column-in-data-frame-that-contains-the-string-as-value) uses grepl, which I don't think can handle vectors of regex patterns.

I've tried max, max.col, and which, alone and in combination with rowwise(), but I just cant seem to get the right answer.  I've also made the data "tidy" using reshape (thanks UCLA IDRE http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-reshape-my-data-in-r/), but I was unable to filter the data appropriately.

```
tidydata <- reshape(data,varying =list(paste0("choice",1:3),
  paste0("score",1:3)),direction="long",v.names=c("choice","score"))  %>%
  arrange(id) %>% filter(expert==choice)
```

I know the column of the expert choice, but lose the connection to the choice.1

The best solution would have a function that returns a factor (right, tie, wrong), where row 3 would return tie.

**Edit:**
This data is comparing the results of a classifier to a human annotator.  The classifier can sometimes yield tied results (the score for 2 or more classes are the same).  I am trying to identify when the classifier is correct (choice1==expert), but not tied (I call this RIGHT);  Tied (when classes selected by the expert and the classifier have the same score, but are not the same code I call this TIE); otherwise the classify is WRONG.
Thank you

Comment: I kind of don't get what 'row 3 would return tie' means.

Comment: Could you produce sample results?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I only can think of using ifelse statements;

```
data %>% mutate(TF1 = choice1 == expert,
            TF2 = choice2 == expert,
            TF3 = choice3 == expert,
            TFs1 = score2 == score1,
            TFs2 = score3 == score1,
            Decision = ifelse(TF1==TRUE, "Right",
                           ifelse(TF2 == TRUE & TFs1 == TRUE | TF3==TRUE & TFs2 == TRUE, "Tie", "Wrong")))
```

This might not be the one that you look for, but will work as you explained.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  For the first row, the expert chose class.1,  My first choice (choice1) was  class.3 so I was wrong. In the second row, the expert chose class.4, my first choice was class.8,  so I was wrong.  The third row, the expert chose class.2,  choice.1,choice,2 and choice.3 are tied. so the answer isn't wrong, it's tied.  The correct answer should be (false, false, tied)

Comment: What about the first row?  you have class.1 as your second choice, but why is it 'wrong'? shouldn't that also be tie?

Comment: The score for the second choice is not equal to the score for the first choice,

Comment: I simplified the example.  I have about 1000 classes.  I couldn't do it this way.